# Can if fit new 105 5700 cranks on my existing 5600BB?

Tags: bottom-bracket, crankset, compatibility

I am refreshing my drive train. I have been running a full 105 5600 set for a couple years. I have an ultegra cassette and chain ready to fit, and I am consdiering crankset/chainring options. Is the new 105 5700 hollow tech compatible with my 5600 Bottom Bracket?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer?

Yes, you can. Any Hollowtech 2 Bottom Bracket is compatible with any other Hollowtech 2 crank set.

There is no difference in size or function between the 5600 BB and the 5700 BB.

Comment: Thanks Zenbike. I thought that would be the answer. It is cheaper (with better availability) for me to buy a crankset than chain wheels.

Comment: If you are satisfied, can you please accept the answer?